# My form validation isn't working because of e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, css

My javascript validation is not working even after I added a status that checks if it returns true or false, I suspect it is because of e.preventDefault(). I'm still learning javascript and sometimes get confused.

```
 const form = document.getElementById("form");
      const name = document.getElementById("username");
      const number = document.getElementById("number");
      const btn = document.querySelector("button.submit");
      let status = false;

      btn.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        if (!checkInputs()) {
          e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          form.submit();
        }
      });

      function checkInputs() {
        const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
        const numberValue = number.value.trim();

        if (usernameValue === "") {
          status = setErrorFor(username, "First Name cannot be empty");
        } else {
          status = setSuccessFor(username);
        }

        if (numberValue === "") {
          status = setErrorFor(lastname, "Last Name cannot be empty");
        } else {
          status = setSuccessFor(lastname);
        }

        return status;
      }

      function setErrorFor(input, message) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        const small = formControl.querySelector("small");
        formControl.className = "form-control error";
        small.innerText = message;
        return false;
      }

      function setSuccessFor(input) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        formControl.className = "form-control success";
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "isn't working"? Say what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead. If you have any error messages in the developer console, share those too.

Comment: I think you need a click event no submit for button.

Comment: Can you make a snippet ?, yes with html too.

Comment: IF you are listening for a submit event, when are you submitting the form again inside of the submit event?

Comment: If you set status to false, the next check will set it to true.... you need to rethink your design. AKA if `username` is an error and `numberValue` is valid, the form will submit. Whatever the last if/else is going to be is what your validation will follow.

Answer (score 1):

Submit event doesn't work on buttons. You need to set your submit event on your form:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    if (!checkInputs()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
```

Comment: He needs more a ``click`` event, he uses the ``form.submit()`` on else, i mean in button, i think your example will cause infinite loop if gets else every time.

Comment: submit() method just sends the request and will not trigger submit event after that so it is safe to use.

Comment: Ok, checking the documentation what you write is true! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit -> ``No **submit event is raised**. In particular, the **form's onsubmit event handler is not run**.``